# Use call inside a forfiles

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I've a script where I want to call a function for each file in a directory. Using `forfiles`, I've been able to list them like:

```
forfiles /p "%myPath%" /c "cmd /c echo @path NAME @file"
```

Note: myPath is a path with spaces, so I had to put it inside `""`.

However, I need to use a function `LaunchRun` I've in my batch file, so I tried:

```
forfiles /p "%myPath%" /c "call:LaunchRun @path @file"
```

Where my function needs that two parameters. The problem is that I'm getting:

> ERROR: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

Translanted:

> Error: System can't find the specified file

Since every example I found did use `/c` option launching a new console, I trid that too, as I did with the `echo` one:

```
forfiles /p "%myPath%" /c "cmd /c call:LaunchRun @path @file"
```

But then I get:

> Intento no válido de llamar una etiqueta por lotes fuera de un archivo
>   de script por lotes.

Translated:

> Invalid attempt to call batch label outside of a file batch script.

That appears cause I'm calling it in a new console.

**What can I do to be able to call my function at the loop**?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a for-loop:

```
for /r "%myPath%" %%a in (*) do call:LaunchRun "%%~a" "%%~nxa"
```